# C - assigning a 'string' rather than a char to a variable to be used by open function

Tags: c, char

I have a variable output formed by:

```
//main function
char *output; //this is how output is defined

//these 3 lines are in some function call
char cmd[50]  // this is how cmd is defined
cmd = "test.txt" //cmd is not initialized this way (cmd = "text.txt"). 
                 //Rather, there is some function call that passes in the 
                 //&output and does some things, inevitably updating cmd 
                 //by adding one character at a time. In this example it will 
                 //go cmd = "t", cmd = "te", ... cmd = "test.txt",
                 //cmd = "test.txt"
*output = cmd; //then at the end of the function I try to set the contents of 
               //output to the cmd.
```

then I try to call open like:

```
int outfile;
outfile = open( *output, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP );
```

but that does not work. However this works:

```
int outfile;
outfile = open( "test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP );
```

When I try and pass in *output I get an error:

```
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; remove *
```

But when I try just output it does not work properly.I am assuming what is being stored in output is just 't' but I need all of it to make this work. Any ideas? The context of this is I am manually trying to do a redirect.

Comment: This is all a bit murky, but one thing for sure: `outfile = open( *output, ...` is wrong, and should be `outfile = open( output, ...`. The first argument to `open` is a `char *`, not a `char`.

Comment: Set output like this `output = &cmd[0];` and open takes a char pointer so you should call it like `open(output, ...);`

Comment: `output = &cmd[0];` is the correct way to get a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Do not write `output = &cmd[0];` when `output = cmd;` does the same thing with less characters and less confusion.

Comment: @n.m. I would argue that it does it with less characters and more confusion, if you don't already understand array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: @user3037172 think about what `*output` means. The `*` isn't magic, it has a well-defined meaning.  `output` is a pointer to `char`. (`char` means a single character).  `*output` means the thing that `output` is pointing to. Since `char *` points to a `char`, `*output` is a single `char`.   So you are trying to pass a single `char` to your functions . You can see this reflected in the compiler "warning".

Comment: @immibis "if you don't already understand array-to-pointer decay" don't use C. Or perhaps start writing code like `printf(&("Hello world"[0]))`.

Answer (score -2):

*output is - You guess it - a char (because output is "ptr to char")
cmd is - you didn't guess - a pointer to char (because it's an array)

So your assignment "*output = cmd" actually will not do anything reasonable.

Try

```
strcpy(output, cmd);
```

or, (much better)

```
strncpy(output, cmd, BUFLEN);
```

(making sure that BUFLEN is equal to the allocated memory at output, and also making sure output is no local variable)

Tobias

Comment: `output` is a local variable, and it is an uninitialized pointer. The right resolution is `output = cmd;` to make the pointer point at the buffer which is already allocated, there is no point in allocating another buffer. Also you use `strncpy` incorrectly; generally speaking, `strncpy` is less safe than `strcpy` and should be avoided.

Comment: @MattMcNabb could you explain why `strncpy` is less safe? http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy all i see is it's at least as safe as `strcpy`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr neither function behaves properly when the source is longer than the destination buffer, but `strncpy` may lull unsuspecting coders into a false sense of security -- and certainly does, judging by the number of wrong uses of it that are in the wild.  (Also `strncpy` does some redundant work when the source is shorter than the buffer).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the string library?